# Javascript: Choosing an object based on a number

Tags: javascript

I am creating a page which randomly asks different the user different questions when the page is refreshed.

I am having trouble to select the appropriate question when the number is generated.

I have the following code:

```js
var question1 = {
    value: 1,
    question: "Question 1!!",
  answer: "Answer 1!!"
}

var question2 = {
 value: 2,
 question: "Question 2!!",
 answer: "Answer 2!!"
}
//There are 2 questions included, but I plan to add more

function startUp(){
 var questionNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
 document.getElementById("form" + questionNumber).innerHTML = //Help here
    //How do I selct the question based upon the number generated, without lots of if statements?
}
```

the startUp function is triggered when the body loads. the ("form" + questionNumber) selects the appropriate place to put the question.

I would like to be able to add more questions later and was looking for a solution that was easy to update as more is added. I have struggled to find away to do this myself, please help!

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var questions = [{
    value    : 1,
    question : "Question 1!!",
    answer   : "Answer 1!!"
}, {
    value    : 2,
    question : "Question 2!!",
    answer   : "Answer 2!!"
}];

function startUp() {
    var questionNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
    document.getElementById("form" + questionNumber).innerHTML = questions[questionNumber].question;
}
```

Comment: `var questionNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);` Instead of `*` you should use `%`

Comment: Why would i do that? That will always resut in 0, not in a random number from 0 to the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As Evan Trimboli said in his comment: "reseach arrays". I would do it like this:

```
var question1 = {
    question: "Question 1!!",
    answer: "Answer 1!!"
}

var question2 = {
    question: "Question 2!!",
    answer: "Answer 2!!"
}

var questions = [question1, question2];
```

And then to get first question you can do:

```
questions[0];
```

Of course you can substitude 0 (first question) for your variable that has a random number.

```
console.log(questions[1].question); // another example
```